# Changing unit test package name with corresponding production code package in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing

I have a package structure containing Unit Tests that corresponds the production code. When I do the refactoring, I often move classes to different packages. In that case I also have to manually move the corresponding Unit Test class to the new package and sometimes I forget to do so. Is there any solution, how to move the corresponding JUnit test class to a corresponding package automatically?

I use Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin called "MoreUnit" which is very helpful for everything concerning working with JUnit tests. It supports what you are looking for. Have a look at http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/